# Is it possible to screenshare an rdp without having it on

Tags: remote-desktop

I have this code that screenshares your screen to a live video which other people can watch, i tried using it on an rdp and it worked but my problem is once i leave the rdp the screen just fades away as the rdp doesn't have a screen. I'm trying to make it so it screenshares normally even if there is no one on the rdp

Comment: when connecting to rdp, you can type /admin in the address: for example `192.168.0.1:3389 /admin` to connect to the console rather than a separate RDP session. this is as if you are directly behind the computer. If you configure to not lock the pc on disconnect, the screen share would keep working as expected. But a program like teamviewwer, anydesk or vnc will definitely work better here.

Answer (score 0):

Not with RDP no, as when connected using that method you're not actually viewing the console/screen itself, at least not how you'd normally think about it. That's the same reason why if you RDP into the computer the actual screen itself becomes locked, and if you unlock the screen to view it the RDP session ends.

Other remote access apps would do it though. Things like Splashtop, Teamviewer etc display the actual screen, so if you connected through one of those apps and shared your screen, if you then disconnect the people viewing the screen would continue to have access.

Comment: You can use the /admin switch to connect directly to console.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but i actually managed to make it so the screen doesn't get locked by using the session ID like this

`
    @echo off
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%i in ('query session ^| findstr "Active"') do set SessionId=%%k
    Tscon %SessionId% /Dest:console
`